# Android Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm moving my app from minSdk 8 targetSdk 19 built in Eclipse to minSdk 14 targetSdk 22 built in Android Studio, since the announcement of withdrawal of Eclipse support.

Rather than allowing Android Studio to perform a conversion, I wanted to create a new project and manually port my code over.

I'm stuck.

I have a main activity which extends from AppCompatActivity and uses a navigation drawer and a toolbar, which all works fine. My fragment loads ok too, until I try to reference the toolbar.

My main activity code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankTestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ...
    ...
```

My loaded fragment code is:

```
public class BlankTestFragment extends Fragment {
...
private Toolbar toolbar;
...
public static BlankTestFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BlankTestFragment fragment = new BlankTestFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public BlankTestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public final static String TAG = BlankTestFragment.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

   toolbar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

}
```

The last line reports:

```
Incompatible Types:
Required: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
Found: android.support.v7.app.Actionbar
```

So, what's going wrong? Where is the Actionbar reference coming from?

**SOLUTION**

In MainActivity I added:

```
public static Toolbar getToolbar(){
    return toolbar;
}
```

In my test fragment, in onAttach, I added:

```
toolbar = MainActivity.getToolbar();
toolbar.setTitle("hello");
```

**SOLUTION 2**

It turns out that just a small error in my test fragment prevented my original implementation from working.

In MainActivity I had set the toolbar to be a SupportActionBar. So when I tried

```
toolbar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

in the fragment, I had set toolbar to be

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
```

but by then it wasn't a ToolBar, so I changed it to

```
private ActionBar toolbar;
```

and everything worked fine.

Comment: your solution is horrible. what happens if you use that fragment in another activity?

Comment: what do you need the toolbar for, anyway?

Comment: I wont be using that fragment in another activity. What's your solution then?

Comment: I need the toolbar to hang my tools on

Comment: My guess is that njzk2's concern is the lack of flexibility. IMHO, the far larger concern is that you are leaking memory like a sieve. Do not put widgets in static data members. If you want to talk to the hosting activity, your fragment can call `getActivity()` and talk to the instance, not the class, calling some `getToolbar()` on the instance. njzk2's concern would be addressed by your casting `getActivity()` to be some interface, rather than a concrete class like `MainActivity`, so that the fragment is not tied to a particular class of hosting activity.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, that is a more constructive criticism of my code than previous comments. I will take your advice on-board and come up with a new solution.

Comment: I didn't want to put toolbar as static, but android studio insisted that it should be. I'm thinking that if my conversion from a pre-lollipop navigation drawer app with fragments loading into mainactivity into a lollipop version of the same with support down to ics isn't working, then my whole approach to the upgrade is wrong, and this entire thread is moot.

Comment: Remember in Java/C# a static method can only access static variables/members. Your solution could be to make a non-static method. Hence I did mention in my post about using MainActivity and reference it, a small hint I admit. Congrats anyway!

Comment: I ask because most things that can be done on the toolbar can also be done on the actionbar. It is possible that you are trying to solve a problem that does not need solving. Another thing that is possible, is to put the toolbar in the layout of the Fragment. Or, you can get it using `(Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);`

Comment: I thought that the toolbar was 'the next great thing' to come out of google and was to replace the actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the Actionbar reference coming from?

The return value of `getSupportActionBar()` is an instance of `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`, as is indicated in [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29). You cannot assign that to a `Toolbar` field, as `Toolbar` does not inherit from `ActionBar`.

Under the covers, `setSupportActionBar()` takes your `Toolbar` and wraps it in another object. I do not see an easy way to get the `Toolbar` back. So, try to work with the `ActionBar` wrapper that `getSupportActionBar()` returns.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my version of the solution at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove code `getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`. Simply replace it with code getting the `toolbar` from `MainActivity` by calling a public get method from that Activity. CommonsWare gave a good hint already.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment combined with CommonsWare helped me reach a solution

Comment: @DaveSav, You may upvote both posted answers as being useful, showing appreciation. Good luck and have fun!